# Разметка на layout

Tags: java, android, разметка

Добавил "глазик" для того, чтобы скрыть/показать вводимый пароль, но editText размещается ниже layout, в который он обернут.

Сама разметка:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/loginfull">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-35dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginEnd="-63dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2" >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp"    />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/auth"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_rectangle"
        android:text="войти"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

И вот что получается:

[image: Видно, что layout расположен как надо]

[image: editText уезжает вниз]

**UPD**
Сделал тоже самое, что было предложено в ответе, результат тот же:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще есть встроенные средства для решения вашей задачи:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/login_spacing_bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/fragment_login_password_hint"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

а именно поле:

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

оно уже встроенное и выравнивать ничего не придется. [Вот есть пример](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-toggle-password-visibility-in-android/) хороший.

### UPDATE

Вот ваша разметка:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-35dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/login"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-63dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/login"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/password_input"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_input"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView2"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/auth"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:text="войти"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

вот как выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это поле и у меня есть. Вопрос в том почему editText съезжает. И пример вы скинули точно такой же как у меня

Comment: приложите пожалуйста всю разметку в вопрос, я попробовал ваше поле для ввода и ничего не съезжает)

Comment: приложил всю разметку

Comment: приложил в обновлении скрин того как у меня она выглядит, перетащил я все под constraintLayout

Comment: не понимаю почему так, сделал как вы предложили, такая же ситуация)

Comment: мож у вас библиотеки устаревшие например? дизайновые штуки может себя плохо поэтому ведут как вариант

Comment: да, действительно, обновил библиотеку и все встало на места, но картинка глаза исчезла)

Comment: так у вас же на скрине картинка глаза присутствует, просто попробуйте убрать все background установки, может где-то цвета конфликтуют